# Getting a error "coInitialize has not been called" while converting a uploaded word file to pdf in django using docx2pdf

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, filefield, django-file-upload

I am trying to convert an uploaded Docx file to pdf in Django using the docx2pdf module.But when I pass the file into the convert function I am getting the following error,

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221008, 'CoInitialize has not been called.', None, None)
```

My views.py:

```
def post(self, request):
        files=request.FILES.getlist("files")
        for f in files:
            file_type=getFileType(f)[-1]
            final_pdf=f
            file_type == ".docx":
            new_file= File()
            fs = FileSystemStorage()
            file_name = fs.save(f.name, f)
            uploaded_file_url = fs.url(file_name)
            convert('media/'+f.name) 
            new_file.file.save(f.name.split(".")[0]+".pdf",f,save=False)
            new_file.save()    
        resp={"message": "Files Uploaded"}
        return Response(resp, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Having the same issue, did you got the answer?